# Redirect old directory in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have a website in which I'm removing a subdirectory name for SEO purposes:

Current: website.com/sito/ceretta-brasiliana
New: website.com/ceretta-brasiliana

I need to redirect all requests from "sito" to the new url basically removing the subdirectory "sito" but maintaining the rest of the URL (in that case, "ceretta-brasiliana").

Is anyone able to help me with the regular expression?

Thanks, Andrea

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple `Redirect` in your htaccess

```
 Redirect 301 /sito/ https://website.com/
```

Comment: Thanks but "ceretta-brasiliana" is just an example. I'd want that everything that come after /sito/ will be the same in the new url so, for example

website.com/sito/page-name

will become

website.com/page-name

where page-name is whatever name of whatever page. Sorry for not explaining myself clearly

Comment: @AndreaMarucci okay got it. The edit should work.

Comment: Thanks. I've yet used this but it simply don't keep any string after the /sito/ part so redirect everything on the home page.

Comment: @AndreaMarucci This redirects `/sito/foobar` to `/foobar` . Try clearing your browser cache.